# Updating a bare git repository from a git-svn cloned remote repository

Tags: git, git-svn

I have a remote SVN repository (X) where a freelance developer is committing his work. However, in my company we work with GIT and are using git-svn to interoperate GIT and SVN. That's ok!

So, I've cloned the SVN repository (X) into a GIT local repository (A). After this, I've made a clone of the local git repository (A) into a local GIT bare repository (B) to be able to pull it from everywhere through SSH.

The problem is: everytime the developer commits to his SVN repository, I do "git svn fetch && git svn rebase" in order to get updates local repos (A) , but I can't update my local bare repository (B) from A. From B, I ran "git fetch", so it fetched changes from (A) into FETCH_HEAD, but I want to "merge" these changes to the bare repository (B) HEAD, so that I can pull changes from a remote repos.

Any ideas?

I hope I've been clear enough. Thanks!

Comment: Would be interested in the solution you picked. I have a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

In Git, merging requires a working copy in order to actually perform the merge (because there might be conflicts). This is probably why you can't merge inside your bare repository (B).

What you can do is merge in your working repository (A), then *push* the result of the merge to repository (B).

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer - You can push from A to the bare repository B.

Answer (score 0):

You may install [SubGit](http://subgit.com) into your repository X, so that a bare Git repository (Y) will be created on that machine, so that syhchroinzation X<->Y will be performed automatically.
So you may use Y as a replacement of B or sync them by running "git pull --all " on B periodically. The repository A is redundant in this case.